# Factoriality of schubert cells in affine flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, schemes, geometric-representation-theory

Take for simplicity $G=SL_n$ and consider the affine flag variety $Fl=G(\mathbb{C}((t)))/I$ for  $I$ the Iwahori corresponding to the Borel of upper triangular matrices of determinant one.

For each $w\in\widetilde{W}$, the affine Weyl group, one has the schubert cell $X_{w}=\overline{IwI}/I$, that is a normal projective variety.

One knows by Kumar's book on Kac-moody groups, that $Pic(X_{w})=\mathbb{Z}$, which ones are locally factorial? In other words, when do we have that $Pic(X_{w})=Cl(X_{w})$?

Comment: Maybe it is better to call this "Schubert variety", not "Schubert cell".